# Why are both class instances changed?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was reading [this article](https://kite.com/blog/python/functional-programming) about functional programming in Python (3).

However I don't understand this example in the text:

```
class Bus(object):
     passengers = set()
     def add_passenger(self, person):
        self.passengers.add(person)

bus1 = Bus()
bus2 = Bus()
bus1.add_passenger('abe')
bus2.add_passenger('bertha')
bus1.passengers  # returns ['abe', 'bertha']
bus2.passengers  # also ['abe', 'bertha']
```

Why would calling add_passenger() on bus1 instance of the class change the passenger set of bus2?

And what would be the correct way to do it when you don't want this behaviour?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why would calling add_passenger() on bus1 instance of the class change the passenger set of bus2?

Because there *is* no "passenger set *of `bus2`*" (and no passenger set *of `bus1`*). In this code:

```
class Bus(object):
     passengers = set()
```

...`passengers` is a class variable which is shared among all instances of this class, yet *belongs* not to these instances, but to the *class itself*, so when you change `self.passengers`, you actually change `Bus.passengers`, and since `bus1.passengers` and `bus2.passengers` *refer to* `Bus.passengers`, `bus1.passengers == bus2.passengers` is always true.

If you do not want this behaviour, implement an `__init__` method:

```
class Bus:
    def __init__(self):
        self.passengers = set()
```